# R DT filter for comma-separated text with multi-select

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

I have a dataframe with a **weekday column**. In it can be *one weekday* or *multiple weekdays*, comma separated.
I want to show the table with the filter on top and the weekdays column should behave like a factor filter, so the multi-select pops-up with the 7 possible weekdays.

I tried with the yadcf Datatables plugin: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(href="jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css", rel = "stylesheet"),
    tags$script(src="jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"),
  ),
  dataTableOutput("sometable")
)

jsc <- '
    function(settings, json) {
        var table = settings.oInstance.api();
        yadcf.init(table, [{
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          data: [{"label": "Montag", "value": 1}, {"label": "Dienstag", "value": 2}, {"label": "Mittwoch", "value": 3},
                 {"label": "Donnerstag", "value": 4}, {"label": "Freitag", "value": 5}, {"label": "Samstag", "value": 6}, {"label": "Sonntag", "value": 7}],
          omit_default_label: true,
          //filter_type: "multi_select",
          text_data_delimiter: ","
        }]);
    }
'

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sometable <- renderDataTable({
    df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                     Weekdays = c("Montag", "Dienstag,Mittwoch", "Mittwoch,Samstag",
                                  "Donnerstag", "Montag,Freitag", "Samstag,Sonntag"))

    datatable(df, filter = "top",
              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(jsc))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

EDIT: This JS works, but I would like the multi-select to look nicer, like a normal select input and actually I would like that select instead of the default one from `filter="top"`.

```
jsc <- '
    function(settings, json) {
        var table = settings.oInstance.api();
        yadcf.init(table, [{
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          data: ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag","Sonntag"],
          sort_as: "num",
          omit_default_label: true,
          filter_type: "multi_select",
          text_data_delimiter: ","
        }]);
    }
'
```

[image]

---

EDIT 2:

Ideally I would like the behaviour in this example in the `Tags` column
https://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed `data` and `omit_default_label` and it works fine. Is it what you want?

```r
library(DT)

js <- '
      yadcf.init(table, [
        {
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          //data: [{"label": "Montag", "value": 1}, {"label": "Dienstag", "value": 2}, {"label": "Mittwoch", "value": 3},
          //       {"label": "Donnerstag", "value": 4}, {"label": "Freitag", "value": 5}, {"label": "Samstag", "value": 6}, {"label": "Sonntag", "value": 7}],
          //omit_default_label: true,
          text_data_delimiter: ","
        }
      ]);
'

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                 Weekdays = c("Montag", "Dienstag,Mittwoch", "Mittwoch,Samstag",
                              "Donnerstag", "Montag,Freitag", "Samstag,Sonntag"))

dtable <- datatable(
  df, #filter = "top",
  callback = JS(js)
)

dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "yadcf", "0.9.3",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.3/"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "jquery-ui", "1.12.1",
  src = "www/shared/jqueryui/",
  script = "jquery-ui.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery-ui.css",
  package = "shiny")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "moment", "2.27.0",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/"),
  script = "moment.min.js")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))

dtable
```

[image]

---

## Edit

To get the desired order:

```r
library(DT)

js <- '
      yadcf.init(table, [
        {
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          data: [
            {"label": "Montag", "value": "Montag"}, 
            {"label": "Dienstag", "value": "Dienstag"}, 
            {"label": "Mittwoch", "value": "Mittwoch"},
            {"label": "Donnerstag", "value": "Donnerstag"}, 
            {"label": "Freitag", "value": "Freitag"}, 
            {"label": "Samstag", "value": "Samstag"}, 
            {"label": "Sonntag", "value": "Sonntag"}
          ],
          //omit_default_label: true,
          filter_type: "select",
          select_type: "jquery-ui",
          text_data_delimiter: /,/
        }
      ]);
'

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                 Weekdays = c("Montag", "Dienstag,Mittwoch", "Mittwoch,Samstag",
                              "Donnerstag", "Montag,Freitag", "Samstag,Sonntag"))

dtable <- datatable(
  df, #filter = "top",
  callback = JS(js)
)

dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "yadcf", "0.9.3",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.3/"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "jquery-ui", "1.12.1",
  src = "www/shared/jqueryui/",
  script = "jquery-ui.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery-ui.css",
  package = "shiny")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "moment", "2.27.0",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/"),
  script = "moment.min.js")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))

dtable
```

[image]

---

## Edit: nice multi select

If you want to have a nice multi select, you have to set the option `select_type=select2` but you also have to include the **select2** library.

```r
library(DT)

js <- '
      yadcf.init(table, [
        {
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          data: [
            {"label": "Montag", "value": "Montag"}, 
            {"label": "Dienstag", "value": "Dienstag"}, 
            {"label": "Mittwoch", "value": "Mittwoch"},
            {"label": "Donnerstag", "value": "Donnerstag"}, 
            {"label": "Freitag", "value": "Freitag"}, 
            {"label": "Samstag", "value": "Samstag"}, 
            {"label": "Sonntag", "value": "Sonntag"}
          ],
          //omit_default_label: true,
          filter_type: "multi_select",
          select_type: "select2",
          text_data_delimiter: /,/
        }
      ]);
'

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                 Weekdays = c("Montag", "Dienstag,Mittwoch", "Mittwoch,Samstag",
                              "Donnerstag", "Montag,Freitag", "Samstag,Sonntag"))

dtable <- datatable(
  df, #filter = "top",
  callback = JS(js)
)

dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "yadcf", "0.9.3",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.3/"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "jquery-ui", "1.12.1",
  src = "www/shared/jqueryui/",
  script = "jquery-ui.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery-ui.css",
  package = "shiny")
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "select2_js", "4.0.13",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/"),
  script = "js/select2.min.js",
  stylesheet = "css/select2.min.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "moment", "2.27.0",
  c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/"),
  script = "moment.min.js")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))

dtable
```

[image]

---

## Edit: in Shiny

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

js <- '
      yadcf.init(table, [
        {
          column_number : 2,
          column_data_type: "text",
          data: [
            {"label": "Montag", "value": "Montag"}, 
            {"label": "Dienstag", "value": "Dienstag"}, 
            {"label": "Mittwoch", "value": "Mittwoch"},
            {"label": "Donnerstag", "value": "Donnerstag"}, 
            {"label": "Freitag", "value": "Freitag"}, 
            {"label": "Samstag", "value": "Samstag"}, 
            {"label": "Sonntag", "value": "Sonntag"}
          ],
          //omit_default_label: true,
          filter_type: "multi_select",
          select_type: "select2",
          text_data_delimiter: /,/
        }
      ]);
'

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:6,
                 Weekdays = c("Montag", "Dienstag,Mittwoch", "Mittwoch,Samstag",
                              "Donnerstag", "Montag,Freitag", "Samstag,Sonntag"))

dtable <- datatable(
  df, #filter = "top",
  callback = JS(js)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "yadcf", "0.9.3",
      c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.3/"),
      script = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js",
      stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.css"),
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "select2_js", "4.0.13",
      c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/"),
      script = "js/select2.min.js",
      stylesheet = "css/select2.min.css"),
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "moment", "2.27.0",
      c(href =  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/"),
      script = "moment.min.js")
  ),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: almost, I want the select input to be ordered, thats why i defined the data object, but i think i need a custom filter func. And actually I would like the original `filter="top"` to use that filter instead of the default one.

Comment: I added some JS that works technically, but I dont like the look of it

Comment: @SeGa Do you mean you found a solution?

Comment: not really, I mean the filter works technically but I cant use that solution. I'll post a picture of what i want

Comment: @SeGa I've found something. You have to enter `data` like this: `{"label": "Montag", "value": "Montag"}, etc`.

Comment: The order is nice, but I want to have a multi-select, which gives me the ugly look then..

Comment: @SeGa Ok, I see. Look at my latest edit, this is what you want I think.

Comment: Hm, the selection works only once for me.. I've got DT 0.27

Comment: @SeGa For me too in RStudio, but it works if you open in an ordinary browser.

Comment: Hm, yes the small example works correctly but my bigger one also just selects once and then nothing happens..

Comment: @SeGa Sad... I have no more ideas now, sorry. You use it in Shiny? Did you try `server=FALSE`?

Comment: Yes, I am using shiny and tried server=FALSE with no look.. I'll keep trying

Comment: The solution also doesnt work in shiny.. There seems to be a problem with the dependencies if you attach them this way..

Comment: Can you make it work in shiny? Then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @SeGa See my edit. Works fine for me, even in the RStudio browser.

Comment: indeed, apparently in my bigger shinyapp there seems to be a problem with the web dependencies.. I am trying to find a reproducible example.. For example including a `range_number_slider` from `jqueryui` doesnt seem to work. Sliders and Datetimepicker seem to be an issue

Comment: @SeGa Did you include the **jqueryui** dependency? Note that the one contained in Shiny is a recent version, maybe **yadcf** requires an older version. Try **1.12.1**.

Comment: youre' right, I was using 1.9.2 which didnt work. 1.12.1 works. but the style is still awefull :D

Comment: Thanks for your help! You definitly deserve those points :)